# Store transactionscope in session

Tags: rest, transactions, atomic, transactionscope

I am wondering if it is a proper approach to store TransactionScope in the session in an ASP.NET application to achieve an atomic transaction via several RESTful requests. I checked some relevant articles regarding batch such as this one:

[REST and Batch](http://www.subbu.org/blog/2008/02/rest-and-batch)

However, this approach limits the operations within the batch to be uncorrelated. What I want to achieve is something like:

POST /account to create an account and return the account id
PUT /user/1 to update the user with the returned account id

It could be easily achieved with two RESTful requests. However, I would like to ensure the integrity of the data. Hence, the operation needs to be atomic.

What I could think of is using session to store a TransactionScope object. Make two RESTful requests as usual and commit the transaction in a third request and dispose the TransactionScope object and session.

Could it be a proper approach? Did I miss anything (maybe locks?)

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a particularly bad idea. Restful services are supposed to be stateless.

If you need transactions you should look at WCF...

Comment: Yes. I agree with you to some extent. But from the interoperability perspective, WCF seems not to be a good idea either. How bad could it be if I put TransactionScope in the session (or a cache) and set an expiry for that?